# Is UI Stack Exchange at risk?

Tags: support, area-51

I just discovere UI [Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/), and its [Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728/user-interface) has two issues on "Worrying" status. Should I worry?

Comment: Not if the community gives kick ass high-quality answers

Comment: Wouldn't this belong on the of Meta of UI?

Comment: @Bobby, no as there are lots of Area 51 sites that the same quesions could be asked of, so it is a overall policy question.

Comment: Related: [Please do not close GIS SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68079/please-do-not-close-gis-se)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the related [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/).  The answer is that some sites with worrying status simply will stay in beta longer.  As long as a site has great content, it will be allowed to continue.  If it doesn't, it might be mothballed until it can be improved.

Comment: Well, as long as it's public, it doesn't really matter if it's beta or not. Thanks.